# How to integrate chktex into TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, chktex

How can I integrate the chktex linting and format checking script into TexStudio?

I would like to run chktex automatically on every build and see the output in the messages window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find an answer to how one can integrate chktex into TexStudio, therefore here is my own answer

If someone is interested, this is how to achieve that on Ubuntu through a custom command:

1. install `chktex` (e.g. `sudo apt install chktex`)
2. Open TexStudio -> Options -> Configure TexStudio
3. Enable `Show Advanced Options` in the botttom left
4. Go to `Build` tab and under `User Commands` press `+Add`
5. Command name = `user0:chktex`, command executable = `./chktex %` (the percentage sign is a placeholder for the main file name without extension.
6. Optional: if you want to run chktex for every build, just add the command to the Build & View line by using `txs:///user0`

The final settings should look like this:
[image: TexStudio custom chktex command]

7. Then create the script which runs chktex and checks the output. Note: Running chktex directly as a command would be possible, but it always returns an error exit code, even if there is no error. Therefore we need the additional script:

Save this file besides your main .tex file as `chktex.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: chktex.sh [FileWithoutExtension]"
    exit 1
fi

main_file=$1

if test -f "$DIR/$main_file.chk"; then
    rm $DIR/$main_file.chk
fi

chktex -l $DIR/.chktexrc $DIR/$main_file.tex -o $DIR/$main_file.chk
chk_out=`cat $DIR/$main_file.chk`

if [ ${#chk_out} -gt 0 ]; then
    cat $DIR/$main_file.chk
    rm $DIR/$main_file.chk
    exit 1
else
    echo "chktex did not find any issues"
    exit 0
fi
```

8. Add the `.chktexrc` file to configure chktex for your project. Note: the following file are adapted changes for my project, you may need to adapt them.

```
CmdLine { 
-q
-n 1 # Command terminated with space.
-n 8 # Wrong length of dash may have been used.
-n 12 # Interword spacing (`\ ') should perhaps be used.
-n 13 # Intersentence spacing (`\@') should perhaps be used.
-n 24 # Delete this space to maintain correct pagereferences.
-n 36 # You should put a space in front of parenthesis.

# -n 26 # You ought to remove spaces in front of punctuation.
# -n 11 # You should use \ldots to achieve an ellipsis.
# -n 18 # Use either `` or '' as an alternative to `"'.
# -n 2 # Non-breaking space (`~') should have been used.
}
```

9. Since the output of chktex relies on monospaced font to mark the error position, we need to switch the font from TexStudio's Messages Output to Monospace. To achieve this, open `$HOME/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini` and in the section `[texmaker]` add a new entry with `LogView\FontFamily=DejaVu Sans Mono`
10. Now run your build and you will get chktex output